# How can I trim around flexible tubing coming through drywall?

Tags: wiring, conduit

I have what I believe is referred to as ENT conduit (smurf tube?). How does one terminate this type of conduit where the tube meets the drywall? I was looking for some sort of grommet, but I can't find anything that fits the bill.

There are 10 cat5 cables that need to go out of the conduit, through a hole in the drywall and to my patch panel. I just don't want an ugly hole in the drywall.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't putting network sockets in the wall and using patch cables to jumper them to the patch panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the conduit itself through the drywall so that you can secure it to something such as a wall stud, using a pipe clamp. Use a plumbing escutcheon to close off the hole. I'd recommend caulking around the conduit at the drywall intersection to prevent the drywall from fraying and leaving dust particles behind.